# Gitlab issue while running helm command as - Error: unknown command "sh" for "helm"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a packge script which needs to run on `alpina:helm` image . I have used this before but for some reason this is always giving me error as - `Error: unknown command "sh" for "helm"`

```
package:
  <<: *artifacts
  stage: package
  image: alpine/helm
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - echo $VERSION
    - helm package ./keycloak --app-version=$VERSION
  artifacts:
    paths: 
    - "*.tgz"
```

Can anybody tell me what is the issue here I am not very sure . Helm command should be running as per my assumption but not sure why isnt it .

Comment: [mcve] please! In particular, can you reproduce this outside GitLab using only the Docker image? Also, which precise version of the Docker image did it work with and which one are you using there? Not specifying a version (or at least a constraint like 2.* or so) is inviting trouble, because it will jump to new versions immediately, even if they break backward compatibility.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I believe this is the gitlab step I am talking about . So there is nothing to test Outside Gitlab here. This specific issue is only with the gitlab step only. I am anyway mentioning its alpine/helm which I intent it to be latest version only .My chart is latest version 2 only . So I have no restrictions there .

Comment: GitLab is using Docker to run those stages. So, of course, you could be able to reproduce this outside of GitLab. Question is, whether it's caused by the way GitLab uses Docker or whether it's something it does inside. For a start, try `docker run --rm alpine/helm ...` to execute what you'd expect GitLab to run.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html), the runner in gitlab is started this way

- the runner starts the docker container specified in `image` and uses the entrypoint of this container
- the runner attaches itself to the container
- the runner combines `before_script`, `script` and `after_script` into a single script
- the runner sends the combined script to the container's shell

If you take a look at the entrypoint of the [alpine/helm](https://github.com/alpine-docker/helm/blob/master/Dockerfile) image, you see that the entrypoint is `helm` and when the container starts it runs helm. The gitlab runner expects no entrypoint or that the entrypoint is set to start a shell so you get the `Error: unknown command "sh" for "helm"` as there is no running shell.

With overriding the entrypoint we make sure the runner finds a shell in the container which can execute the script.

```
package:
  stage: package
  image: 
    name: alpine/helm
    entrypoint: [""] 
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  script:
    - echo $VERSION
    - helm package ./keycloak --app-version=$VERSION
  artifacts:
    paths: 
    - "*.tgz"
```

EDIT:
By reading the docs again I changed the entrypoint to an empty entrypoint for docker 17.06 and later (`entrypoint: [""]`) as this is more concise.

Comment: This worked however can you explain what happened here ?

Comment: @danelnelz Perfect answer . Thanks a ton .