# doctl not available in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, digital-ocean

I'm working on building a Gitlab-CI pipeline that deploys an Spring Boot application to a Kubernetes cluster hosted on DigitalOcean.
Fortunately, I'm right at the beginning of doing this so there's very little bloat, and I figured I'd just test that I had everything wired correctly before I went ahead and built some crazy stuff.

Essentially I've got a Gitlab-CI job that pulls this image: `digitalocean/doctl:1.87.0` and I then attempt to run a number of `doctl` commands in the `script` section of the job. The results of this very simple "deploy" script:

```
deploy-to-kubernetes:
  stage: deploy
  image: digitalocean/doctl:1.87.0
  script:
    - doctl --help
```

looked like this:

```
Error: unknown command "sh" for "doctl"
Run 'doctl --help' for usage.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 255
```

After doing a bit of digging and googling and searching and head-scratching, I hit upon this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67289837/gitlab-issue-while-running-helm-command-as-error-unknown-command-sh-for-he), and figured it may apply to the doctl image too, so I then updated my Gitlab-CI job to this:

```
deploy-to-kubernetes:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: digitalocean/doctl:1.87.0
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - doctl --help
```

and the result was this:

```
$ doctl --help
/bin/bash: line 128: doctl: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something absolutely idiotic, but I can't figure out what that is, so if anybody could help out that would be really appreciated, and if you need more information, let me know.

FYI: This is my first question ever posted on StackOverflow, so any feedback on what I need to change, improve etc is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$PATH` contains default values in this image. But `doctl` available in `/app/doctl`. So you can use it this way: `/app/doctl %command%` (eg, `/app/doctl version`)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and opted to just use a regular alpine container and install the doctl tool myself. It's a workaround though.

```yaml
deploy-to-kubernetes:
  stage: deploy
  image: debian:11.6-slim
  before_script:
    - apt update && apt -y upgrade && apt-get install -y curl
    - curl -Lo doctl.tar.gz https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v1.91.0/doctl-1.91.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz && tar xf doctl.tar.gz
    - chmod u+x doctl
    - mv doctl /usr/local/bin/doctl
  script:
    - doctl --help
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here is job that works for me:

```yaml
"Deploy to DigitalOcean":
  image:
    name: digitalocean/doctl:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - job: "Test Docker image"
  script:
    - /app/doctl auth init
    - /app/doctl apps create-deployment $DIGITALOCEAN_STUDENT_BACKEND_ID
  only:
    - master
```

But it also requires `DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN` [variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) with [DigitalOcean token](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/create-personal-access-token/)